# error extending android application class

Tags: java, android

In order to extend my android application class I followed these steps:

1: AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application ... android:name=".ApplicationExt">
```

2: MainActivity.java:

```
public class ApplicationExt extends Application { ... }
```

And then I got this error:

**Class: 'ApplicationExt' is public, should be declared in a file named 'ApplicationExt.java'**

What's wrong with that?

Comment: What dont you understand about the error message?

Comment: Pretty self evident, just rename MainActivity.java to ApplicationExt.java

Answer (score 1):

In Java, every class must be in a file of the same name.  So you can't add a class named X to a file named Y.

In addition-  you probably shouldn't be overriding Application.  There's very little reason to do so.  Early tutorials suggested doing this for global data, but now the suggestion is to use singletons or other standard Java ways of storing data instead.  The only reason to override Application is if you need to add a low memory handler, and that's very uncommon.

Since you're a beginner-  did you meaybe mean to make a new Activity instead?

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I'm trying to save the webview's cache to the SD card following this tutorial: http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/saving-the-android-webview-cache-on-the-sd-card/ . I'm a web developer, learning java in a too practical way... :) Now I fixed the class problem! Thank's again!